# Deploy ASP.NET Core Razor page to Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to host a ASP.NET Core RazorPages project in Azure App Service.
As an example I've created a new project and that's the app I want to publish.

At first: the publish function from VS2019 (CE) failed with an exception. It is a common exception and I'm not investigate more time in in.

So I thought: I publish it using the portal. So i have a Free account of Azure, create a Resource Group, a Hosting Plan and a Web App. Then i've upload my website using OneDrive and that works.

I've add the ASP.NET Core 3.1 (x86) Runtime to the extensions and the stack is .NET Core (32 bit, because of free plan). I've build the app also for x86.

But the application doesn't work. When I add a default Index.html to the application it works (but not the Razor Pages).

Who can solve this problem??

Regards

Donovan

Comment: "Then I've upload my website using OneDrive and that works." How do you know? Did you have a look at the filesystem? What does it hold? Does it have all files needed to run the application, like the wwwroot and website.exe? "But the application doesn't work." How do you know? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @rickvdbosch "Did you have a look at the filesystem?" --> By using the debugconsole, I can see that all the files are there. (https://(myapp).scm.azurewebsites.net/debugconsole). I've also found the (myapp).exe in the bin directories (Debug, Release and x86). The error message is "You do not have permission to view this directory or page".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you copied too many files to your App Service. The `bin/debug` and/or `bin/release` folders should **not** be there. You need to prepare the website for deployment. In Visual Studio, you can do so by doing a right-click on the ASP.NET project and selecting 'Publish'. On the page that opens, configure a local publish to a folder. The contents of that folder should then be copied to the App Service.

For more information, see [Deploy an app to a local folder using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/quickstart-deploy-to-local-folder).

Also interesting: [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy)

> The `dotnet publish` command compiles app code and copies the files required to run the app into a *publish* folder. When deploying from Visual Studio, the `dotnet publish` step occurs automatically before the files are copied to the deployment destination.
>
> **Folder contents**
>   The publish folder contains one or more app assembly files, dependencies, and optionally the .NET runtime.
>
> A .NET Core app can be published as *self-contained deployment* or *framework-dependent deployment*. If the app is self-contained, the assembly files that contain the .NET runtime are included in the *publish* folder. If the app is framework-dependent, the .NET runtime files aren't included because the app has a reference to a version of .NET that's installed on the server. The default deployment model is framework-dependent. For more information, see [.NET Core application deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/).
>
> In addition to *.exe* and *.dll* files, the publish folder for an ASP.NET Core app typically contains configuration files, static assets, and MVC views. For more information, see [ASP.NET Core directory structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/directory-structure?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: @Donovan In case this answer helped you (which it looks like it did) please mark it as an answer for future users stumbling upon this question.